# Mergesort in C not working

Tags: c, arrays, sorting, mergesort

I've got this merge sort implementation that doens't works and I can't figure why.

Here are the methods:

```
    void merge_sort(int A[], int i, int j)
    {
       if(i<j)
       {
           int n = j-i+1;
           int k = n/2;

           merge_sort(A, i, i+k-1);
           merge_sort(A, i+k, j);
           merge(A, i, i+k, j);
       }
    }
```

And that's the merge method:

```
 void merge(int A[], int a, int b, int j)
{
    int* T = malloc(sizeof(int)*DIM);
    int c=0;
    int h=a;

    while(a<b && b<=j)
    {
    if(A[a] > A[b])
        T[c++] = A[a++];
    else
        T[c++] = A[b++];
    }
    while(a<b) T[c++] = A[a++];
    while(b<=j) T[c++] = A[b++];

    c=0;
    while(h<=j)
    A[h++] = T[c++];


}
```

Here is how I call merge_sort:

```
merge_sort(A, 0, DIM-1);
```

where DIM is the length of the array minus one.

That's the output:

```
5 2 4 6 8 9 7 1 3 10 
0 9
0 4
0 1
2 4
3 4
5 9
5 6
7 9
8 9
10 9 8 7 10 6 5 4 3 2
```

The first half is perfectly ordered, the second half minus one also.
I can't figure out where is the problem.

Comment: the code how you call `merge_sort()`is missing. Also where is the output generated? what is DIM? where is the free for T?

Comment: Ok, I'll add it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 2 problems with your code.

1. Calculating boundaries are not correct.
2. You have a incorrect `while` condition.

Incorrect `while` is here:

```
while(a<b && b<=j)
{
if(A[a] > A[b])
    T[c++] = A[a++];
else
    T[c++] = A[b++];
}
```

In this loop, you increase `b` while it is in your condition too which will affect your loop.

Here is is your code that I corrected (`i` in included in array while `j` is excluded):

```
void merge_sort(int A[], int i, int j)
{
   if(j-i>=2) // since j is excluded, this condition means that we have more than 1 member.
   {
       int k = (j+i)/2;

       merge_sort(A, i, k);
       merge_sort(A, k, j);
       merge(A, i, k, j);
   }
}

void merge(int A[], int a, int b, int j)
{
    int* T = malloc(sizeof(int)*DIM);
    int c=0;
    int h=a;
    int m = b;

    while(a<b && m<j) // b and j are excluded
    {
    if(A[a] > A[m])
        T[c++] = A[a++];
    else
        T[c++] = A[m++];
    }
    while(a<b) T[c++] = A[a++];
    while(m<j) T[c++] = A[m++];

    c=0;
    while(h<j)
    A[h++] = T[c++];
}
```

and run it with:

```
merge_sort(A, 0, DIM);
```

Comment: Thank you so much!